# Commit project.pbxproj in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, svn

I just update to new xcode and now the project file stopped being able to be committed or updated. Is there any place I can configure for it to use SVN? Manual sync seems such a pain.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; the only project file I commit to source control is the project.pbxproj (since Xcode's beginnings, now on Xcode 4.2). Is that not what you are doing?

Comment: yes, but on Xcode 4.2 beta that file stopped being tracked.

Comment: Not sure that's Xcode's fault; did you check your svn logs using another tool (like the command-line client)?

Comment: Well, I didn't. This happened right after I upgraded the Xcode. Give this solution (use an external tool) so I can accept your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something happened to your svn repository which may or may not be Xcode's fault; can you diagnose with an external tool (e.g. the svn command-line client) and get back your project.pbxproj?

Answer (score 1):

In the Xcode organizer go to the repositories section and right click your project and select the menu "Repositories Organizer Help", here you will find useful info about your requirement.